# Java Class Boolean not accepting null

Tags: java, reactjs, null, boolean

I am working on a react application with a Java 8 backend. I’m trying to export a filtered table to a CSV file. I have been able to successfully export a table that is filtered only by an array of strings or single value strings. I am having trouble incorporating filters that are Booleans, BUT ONLY when those filters are left null. If the user does not need to filter the table by a boolean column, the value for that filter field is equal to undefined.  A value of undefined cannot be passed through the web service request. To deal with this, I have a ternary operator set like this:

`Boolean === undefined ? null : BooleanValue`

However, I receive null errors

`Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [null]`

I'm guessing by the reference to java.lang.string that null is getting passed as a string value, however, when I try to account for this in my webservice controller it fails before I can see and debug the value.

NOTE: I am using the class Boolean, not the primitive type boolean (lower case). Its my understanding that the class Boolean should be able to have a value of null but that does not seem to be the case here. Is there a way to do this?

React (Get Values being filtered, if filter not set, change undefined to null):

```
  webservice.Loans.dashboard.filteredCSV(
  LoanTable.status,
  LoanTable.engineerEmail,
  LoanTable.issues === undefined ? null : LoanTable.issues).then(/*Do Stuff*/)
```

webservice controller (debugger won't get this far if value = null but will if value = true or false"):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filteredCSV.json")
@ResponseBody
public WebserviceResponse<?>filteredCSV(
    @RequestParam(value="status") ArrayList status,                             
    @RequestParam(value="engineerEmail") ArrayList engineerEmail,
    @RequestParam(value="issues") Boolean issues){

   if(issues.equals("null")){
        issues = new Boolean(null);
    }

return service.filteredCSV(status, engineerEmail, issues);
}
```

Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Set `required` to false then the `issues` parameter will be nullable.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filteredCSV.json")
@ResponseBody
public WebserviceResponse<?>filteredCSV(
    @RequestParam(value="status") ArrayList status,                             
    @RequestParam(value="engineerEmail") ArrayList engineerEmail,
    @RequestParam(value="issues", required=false) Boolean issues){

     return service.filteredCSV(status, engineerEmail, issues);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. However, that didn't seem to work for me. I still get the same error, `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleTypeMismatch) - Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [null]`

Comment: Is the issues request parameter set?

Comment: Yes, I edited my OP to show where the value of issues is being set. 
Also, I can see the web request being sent in Chrome Network Requests, and the value of undefined is being set to null. not sure if this matters. This request then get directed to the web service controller. As I mentioned above, if I get issues to true or false the filter works and I can export but if that filter doesn't get used its initial value is undefined. If its undefined I give it a value of null.

Comment: Does the actual physical request contain an `issues` parameter?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell. Its getting set form the values in a web request:

http://localhost:8080/filteredCSV.json?status=UNDER_ACTIVE_REVIEW,AUTHORIZED_BY_DWB,UNDER_CONSTRUCTION,CONSTRUCTION_COMPLETED&engineerEmail=null&issues=null

Comment: I don't believe it is not going to accept `issues=null`,  you  need to leave it out of the query parameters if it is not set